# Use Magento2 APIs in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, magento2

I am trying to use Magento2 APIs in my React Native application.

I have created a **new integration** on Magento Admin, but I don't know how to use it.

(any hint about using Magento Integrations would be helpful)

please help and thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a post request using axios or fetch to get admin token
POST /V1/integration/admin/token

login using service credentials for magento integration and you can access magento 2 functionality easily.

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html

This app i have built using magento 2 as backend
https://expo.io/@gamingumar/lemoncrate